# Customization And Localization Of abp.io Default Validation Error Messages

Tags: localization, customization, aspnetboilerplate, abp, validationmessage

How can I Customize And Localize Of abp.io Default Validation Error Messages ?
I would add translated message for another language, instead of "The {fieldName} field is required."
How to do it in abp.io ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see the Extending Existing Resource section [here](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Localization#extending-existing-resource). [AbpValidationResource](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.Validation/Volo/Abp/Validation/Localization/AbpValidationResource.cs) is the resource type. You can find all the [localization keys here](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.Validation/Volo/Abp/Validation/Localization/en.json).
I suggest you to fully read and understand the Localization document. Then you can make it easily. You will create translation JSON files in your application, make the files "embedded" then extend the resource.

If you want to add a new language and contribute to the ABP Framework, you can also see the Resource Localization section of the [contribution guide](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Contribution/Index#resource-localization).

Comment: Lots of thanks @hikalkan
So, I have another question...

HOW can I ask a question directly from YOU or boilerplate (abp.io) team ?